# Рандомный генератор фраз/ошибка: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Проблема возникла со словами после знака присвоения.

```
public class RandomPhrase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      // создаём три списка слов
      String[] list1 = {"чебурек", "дятел", "унитаз", "Шуня", "мясник", "пчела", "китаец"};
      String[] list2 = {"рубит", "строит", "готовит", "учит", "носит"};
      String[] list3 = {"мясо", "жука", "мыло", "домашку", "человека"};

      // определяем кол-во слов в массиве
      int Lenght1 = list1.lenght;
      int Lenght2 = list2.lenght;
      int Lenght3 = list3.lenght;

      // генерируем рандомное число
      int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght1);
      int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght2);
      int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght3);

      // строим фразу
      String phrase = list1[rand1] + " " + list2[rand2] + " " + list3[rand3];

      // выводим фразу
      System.out.println(phrase);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка возникла с 11, 12, 13 строками.( проблема возникла со словами после знака присвоения)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильное название свойства длины массива. У Вас `lenght`, а надо `length`

```
public class RandomPhrase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      // создаём три списка слов
      String[] list1 = {"чебурек", "дятел", "унитаз", "Шуня", "мясник", "пчела", "китаец"};
      String[] list2 = {"рубит", "строит", "готовит", "учит", "носит"};
      String[] list3 = {"мясо", "жука", "мыло", "домашку", "человека"};

      // определяем кол-во слов в массиве
      int Lenght1 = list1.length;
      int Lenght2 = list2.length;
      int Lenght3 = list3.length;

      // генерируем рандомное число
      int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght1);
      int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght2);
      int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * Lenght3);

      // строим фразу
      String phrase = list1[rand1] + " " + list2[rand2] + " " + list3[rand3];

      // выводим фразу
      System.out.println(phrase);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: @DmitryJav1 Если вопрос решен - Отметьте пожалуйста вопрос как правильный. Спасибо!

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar +

Answer (score 0):

Я,разумеется, понимаю, что опечатка в lenght - корень зла, но, как по мне, это наименьшая из проблем данного кода. А наибольшая проблема - процедурный подход и очень плохая расширяемость. Предалагаю старое-доброе ООП и немного функционалки :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RandomPhrase {

    private final List<String[]> phraseList;

    public RandomPhrase(){
        this.phraseList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public RandomPhrase addPhrases(String...phrase){
        phraseList.add(phrase);
        return this;
    }

    public String createPhrase(){
        return phraseList.stream()
                .map(arr->arr[(int)(Math.random()*arr.length)])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RandomPhrase randomPhrase = new RandomPhrase()
                .addPhrases("чебурек", "дятел", "унитаз", "Шуня", "мясник", "пчела", "китаец")
                .addPhrases("рубит", "строит", "готовит", "учит", "носит");

        System.out.println(randomPhrase.createPhrase());
        System.out.println(randomPhrase.createPhrase());

        System.out.println("************************************************");
        randomPhrase.addPhrases("мясо", "жука", "мыло", "домашку", "человека");

        System.out.println(randomPhrase.createPhrase());
        System.out.println(randomPhrase.createPhrase());

    }

}
```

В методе main создаем экземпляр класса RandomPhrase и зразу же добавляем 2 массива слов.
После чего дважды генерируем фразу (пока из 2 слов, потому сто добавили только 2 масиива).
Добавляем еще один массив и генерируем 2 фразы снова, теперь получаем фразы из 3 слов.